# turning user input in n into an if else statement

Tags: java

I have been trying to get user input and based on what they put turn it into a result, every time that i change it. else statement doesn't work, can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
    String heads = "Heads";
    String tails = "Tails";
    
    
    System.out.println("Please choose (H)eads or (T)ails:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputs = in.nextLine();

    String H = "H";
    String T = "T";
    if(inputs == H) {
        String choice = "0";
    }else if(inputs == T) {
        String choice ="1";
    }else {
        System.out.println("Please try again");
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you have to use `string1.equals(string2);` to compare strings.

In your case:

```
if(inputs.equals(H)) {
    String choice = "0";
} else if(inputs.equals(T)) {
    String choice = "1";
} else {
    System.out.println("Please try again");
}
```

Comment: Thank you that did it

Comment: If you think this answer is right, you can accept it using the left check